# Symfony: login using same firewall multiple authentication methods

Tags: symfony, authentication, ldap, firewall, provider

I've been struggling with this for weeks now.
I have a database with a list of users. Some of these users have a Windows domain user, the others don't.
I wish to authenticate the Windows domain users against the active directory (and retrieve their data from the database), the others against the database (and retrieve their data from the database). Both of these things work separately (if I define only one of them for the firewall), but I can't make them both work. 
Could any one give some hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the authentication chain provider like the example in the configuration [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html):

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    foo: { password: test }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```